# IPV6 Record Vs. IPV4 DNS Record

Tags: dns, webserver, ipv6, ipv4

I have been configuring my web application recently, and it came time to configure my DNS. I created an AAAA record over an A record, but only because I block SSH over IPv4. Is there any advantages when comparing AAAA to A records or is the record type just up to preference?

Comment: `A` records are strictly for IPv4 addresses and a `AAAA` are strictly for IPv6 addresses. These record types are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` records always contain an IPv4 address and `AAAA` records are for storing an IPv6 address. Therefore clients which only have IPv4 access to the internet will *only* look for A records. Similarly, IPv6-only clients will only look for AAAA records.  (And no, putting an IPv4 address in an AAAA record will not actually allow any of them to connect.)

Sot the *only* thing that is up to your preference is whether you want IPv4-only users to be able to reach your server or not. Currently a very large portion of internet users still only have IPv4 and nothing else.

Meanwhile, when a client supports both IPv4 and IPv6, it will look for both record types at once, and will order them according to its own preference. (There are OS-wide rules, some programs ignore them and use their own rules, and browsers try both simultaneously according to RFC 8305.)